# logger is changing after init if I call logging.config.dictConfig

Tags: python, logging

I have 2 loggers

```
logger = logger_setup.get_logger_setup(env, logger_name = 'root',  report_to_logging_service=report_to_logging_service)
print len(logger.handlers) # =3
auditor = logger_setup.get_logger_setup(env, logger_name = 'audit')
print len(logger.handlers) # =2
```

inside `get_logger_setup` there is

```
logging.config.dictConfig(my_logging_configs)
```

And if I don't call it the second time The `len(logger.handlers)` remains 3.

I have to call it every time I init a new logger in case of different settings.

Tried to deep copy `copy.deepcopy(logger)` to create a separate object that will not be coupled to `logging.config.dictConfig` but it error since it's a complex object.

ideas?

Comment: what's get_logger_setup? it seems not official function, could you paste def part here

Comment: hi @linpingta, I've explained the part inside get_logger_setup that's causing the issue. it's `logging.config.dictConfig`

Comment: `dictConfig` is meant to be called *once* to configure all loggers and handlers, not multiple times.

Comment: @VinaySajip can you suggest a robust code for that. you can post it as an answer and i'll accept. thanks

Comment: how would you check if `logging.config.dictConfig` was called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure all of your loggers, handlers, filters etc. in a *single* `dictConfig()` call. [This page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#examples) has numerous example configurations that you can use as a starting point. One such (more complex than you might need, but the linked page has simpler examples) is given below:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'special': {
            '()': 'project.logging.SpecialFilter',
            'foo': 'bar',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'myproject.custom': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `dictConfig()` is made in application (i.e. *your*) code - and should not be in the code of any libraries you use. If any of them are doing logging configuration beyond what's recommended for libraries in the Python documentation, then issues should be raised with their maintainers to rectify this.